# How to alternate the color from a Textview which is being update in Android?

Tags: android, colors, textview

I have developed an app in Android capable of detecting the signal of a bluetooth and show them in a Listview. It shows the name, address and the rssi value. For this last parameter I have done it so that is being updated constantly. The thing is that I want the value of rssi to alternate between 2 different colors or more when it updates its value; for example the value is -83dBm in black and the updated value is -81dBm in red. I have tried doing one way but when it runs it doesn't show any value due to trying to change the color. Here is the code I use:

New: Code Edited!!!

```
public class BleDevicesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

private final ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> leDevices;
private final HashMap<BluetoothDevice, Integer> rssiMap = new HashMap<BluetoothDevice, Integer>();

public BleDevicesAdapter(Context context) {
    leDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi) {
    if (!leDevices.contains(device)) {
        leDevices.add(device);
    }
    rssiMap.put(device, rssi);
}

public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
    return leDevices.get(position);
}

public void clear() {
    leDevices.clear();
}

public Integer getRSSI(int j){
    BluetoothDevice device = leDevices.get(j);
    return rssiMap.get(device);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return leDevices.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return leDevices.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    // General ListView optimization code.
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
        viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
        viewHolder.deviceRssi = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_rssi);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    BluetoothDevice device = leDevices.get(i);
    final String deviceName = device.getName();
    if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
        viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
    else
        viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());

        if(viewHolder.deviceRssi.getCurrentTextColor()==0x000000){
        viewHolder.deviceRssi.setTextColor(0xFF0000);
        viewHolder.deviceRssi.setText(""+rssiMap.get(device)+" dBm");

        }
        else {
                    viewHolder.deviceRssi.setTextColor(0x000000);
            viewHolder.deviceRssi.setText(""+rssiMap.get(device)+" dBm");

        }

    return view;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView deviceName;
    TextView deviceAddress;
    TextView deviceRssi;
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is simple.

Inside your `Adapter`:

```
if(value > yourdesiredmax) TextView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
else TextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

When using **if-statemens**, inside `ListView` `Adapters`, it is very important to also provide the opposite state inform of an **else-statement**. The reason therefore is that the `ListView` resuses its `Views` and things can get messed up.

Comment: hi. I have edited the code above and put the whole adapter's code. In where should I put the code you have put? What is the meaning of "value" and "yourdesiremax"?

Comment: that is the condition upon which your text should turn red. you can put in whatever you want as your condition